# Error wiht spark/sqoop to db2 due Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: apache-spark, db2, sqoop

Getting below error when trying to import data from db2 to hdfs using sqoop and spark.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][3.66.46] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server ip-xx.xx.xx.ec2.interna  on port 50,000 with message:
```

I am able to get data When trying with spark local mode. but getting above error with yarn mode

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old jdbc 3.0 driver  (from Db2 V10.5 fixpack 0 (GA).

Upgrade to the latest jdbc 4.0 driver (db2jcc4.jar) version 4.26.14 or higher.

In some cases this upgrade will resolve DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException issues.

Download it from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads).

If the symptom repeats, do more problem determination. 
Connection timeouts (sqlcode=-4499) are almost always configuration errors.

Specifically verify that the cluster name/address and port-number are correct, that there are no firewall issues, and take a jdbc trace to see what is happening under the covers (needs  study).

The Db2 Knowledge Centre online details how to collect a jdbc trace at the client side [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html).

The Db2 Knowledge Centre also gives details of how to increase the [TCPIP connection timeout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0058555.html) if the route between client and server is complicated or has latency issues.

Comment: I tried with all the latet 4.0 jars . but still getting same error.

Comment: Stage 0:> 20/04/06 16:55:57 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-xxxx.ec2.internal, executor 1): com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.26.14] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server ip-xxxx.ec2.internal/ on port 50,000 with message: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: same is working in spark local mode. i am clue less whats happening there

Comment: It is working with spark local mode. port and ip are correct .